# Python: from lists, build dict with key:value ratio not 1:1

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Pardon me for not finding a better title.

Say I have two lists:

```
list1 = ["123", "123", "123", "456"]
list2 = ["0123", "a123", "1234", "null"]
```

which describe a mapping (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11657471/1142160)). I want to create a `dict` from those lists, knowing that `list1` contains the keys and `list2` the values. The `dict` in this case should be:

```
dict1 = {"123":("0123", "a123", "1234"), "456":("null",)}
```

because `list1` informs us that `"123"` is associated to three values.

How could I programmatically generate such a dictionary?

Comment: I don't see how "null" would become "4567"; is the former an error?

Comment: `"456":("null",)` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is your friend:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> result = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
...    result[key] += (value,)
...
```

This produces tuples; if lists are fine, use Jon Clement's variation of the same technique.

Comment: Well, everyone went for a defaultdict, but +1 for keeping with tuples consistent with OP

Comment: Thanks. It's a sad thing having to accept an answer when all provided are equally valid, but as Jon said, you kept in line with tuples.

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in zip(list1, list2):
    dd[key].append(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list1 = ["123", "123", "123", "456"]
>>> list2 = ["0123", "a123", "1234", "null"]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, key in enumerate(list1):
...     d[key].append(list2[i])
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'123': ['0123', 'a123', '1234'], '456': ['null']})
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

And a non-defaultdict solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

dict( (k, tuple(map(itemgetter(1), v))) for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(list1,list2)), itemgetter(0)))
```

Comment: Ha! non-defaultdict, iterative _and_ functional (`map`). :)