# Combine two lists in one dictionary that takes unique values as keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this two lists, with same len:

```
owner=["John","John","Mark","Bill","John","Mark"]
restaurant_number=[0,2,3,6,9,10]
```

I want to turn that into a dict that informs the restaurant_number of each owner:

```
d={"John":[0,2,9],"Mark":[3,10],"Bill":[6]}
```

I could do it the ugly way:

```
unique=set(owner)
dict={}
for i in unique:
    restaurants=[]
    for k in range(len(owner)):
        if owner[k] == i:restaurants.append(restaurant_number[k])
    dict[i]=restaurants
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do that?

Comment: This question is commonly asked (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659398/python-from-lists-build-dict-with-keyvalue-ratio-not-11 ) but there isn't a particularly good duplicate for it. I have wondered about it many times over the years and each time I come to the conclusion that no, there isn't really a better way. That is, you can round off some of the edges with stuff like `defaultdict` and by zipping the inputs together, but you can't avoid an imperative for loop without hurting big-O performance.

Comment: It's also hard to search for duplicates because it's hard to describe the problem statement both concisely and specifically.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you for finding that duplicate. That was the first thing I searched for because I was sure there was already an answer, but I wasn't able to locate it.

Comment: I have a dupe hammer, but I don't feel like I want to use it here....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) + [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) could work here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

owner = ["John", "John", "Mark", "Bill", "John", "Mark"]
restaurant_number = [0, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10]

for o, n in zip(owner, restaurant_number):
    d[o].append(n)

print(dict(d))
```

```
{'John': [0, 2, 9], 'Mark': [3, 10], 'Bill': [6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without dependencies.

Given your input:

```
owner=["John","John","Mark","Bill","John","Mark"]
restaurant_number=[0,2,3,6,9,10]
```

Prepare the recipient dictionary `res` having empty list as values, then populate it without the need to zip:

```
res = {own: [] for own in set(owner)}

for i, own in enumerate(owner):
  res[own].append(restaurant_number[i])
```

To get the result

```
print(res)
#=> {'Mark': [3, 10], 'Bill': [6], 'John': [0, 2, 9]}
```